# Multiple yaml configuration file for the same environment in spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, profile

I have a yaml file(application-dev.yaml) for Dev environment that holds student properties say for example student1. We run a process for each student separately. Now , I need to add properties for student2. In order to reduce ambiguity, we are trying to include the student2 properties in another yaml file(application-dev2.yaml). When the Dev profile is active, I want both the profiles(application-dev.yaml and applocation-dev2.yaml) to be active and the process should be executed for both the student properties.
I tried to include the following code on application.yaml.

```
spring:
  profiles:
    group:
      dev:
        - "dev"
        - "dev2"
```

Executed :
-Dspring.profiles.active=dev

Both the profiles(dev and dev2) are a active but the application-dev2.yaml file is overriding the application-dev.yaml file properties. Thus only student2 properties are executed in the process. Could anyone please advise on the correct approach to be used for this scenario.
Thanks!

Comment: If they have the same name they are going to override each other that is the whole point of properties and multiple files.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @M.Deinum. So all the student(both student1 and student2) properties should be added in the same yaml file is it? Going forward we might need to add n number of Student properties in the dev yaml file which might lead to a very large file. Is there any way we can overcome this ?  We wanted to know if we can place each Student properties in separate yaml file in order to avoid large yaml files.

Comment: I nowhere said that. The properties need to have different names else they override each other, be it in a single or multiple files. In the end there is only 1 large properties object holding the properties, which is basically a key/value map for 1 key there can be only 1 value not multiple.